# What should my next step be after implementing Dependency Injection?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I currently have DI implemented like so and wanted to know what should my next step be to make it easier on myself (and others in the future) when managing all these dependencies?

I have seen a lot of comments regarding a DI/IoC framework, but I don't think my current codebase is big enough to warrant such an implementation .. but I could be wrong and I would like some opinions.

**Below is just an example I concocted to portray what my actual code looks currently looks like.**

```js
class Computer() {
  constructor(private readonly motherboard: Motherboard) {}
}

class Motherboard() {
  constructor(private readonly gfxCard: Graphics,
              private readonly soundCard: Sound) {}
}

class Graphics() {
  constructor(private readonly heatSink: HeatSink,
              private readonly fan: Fan) {}
}

class Sound() {
  constructor() {}
}

// Create a computer
const computer: Computer = new Computer(
                             new Motherboard(
                               new Graphics(
                                 new HeatSink(), new Fan()
                               ),
                               new Sound())) {}
}
```